# Программирование под Android: как полностью настроить программно заданный элемент?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Допустим, мы хотим программно добавить какой-нибудь элемент, например поле ввода или кнопку. Вопрос: как полностью настроить **любые** XML-свойства добавляемого объекта, такие как размер, цвет шрифта, текст подсказки (для поле ввода) и другие? Я не нашёл соответствующего метода.

В [этом](http://androiddocs.ru/programmnoe-sozdanie-elementov-view-ekrana/) примере у кнопки и `TextView` были настроены длина и ширина через метод `LayoutParams`. Но: во-первых, видимо этот метод уже не используется, и требуется указать более точный метод, например **RelativeLayout.LayoutParams** (допускаю, что сказанное выше может быть бредом новичка, потому прилагаю скриншот ниже).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Во-вторых, я не могу настроить таким же образом другие XML-свойства.
Как это правильно делается?

Answer (score 2):

Какой именно выбрать `LayoutParams` зависит от слоя в котором будет находится данный элемент, т.е. если он находится в `RelativeLayout`, то необходимо выбрать `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`, если в `LinearLayout` то `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` и т.п.

По поводу остальных настроек таких как установка текста (`setText`), выбор шрифта (`setTypeface`) и т.д. вы можете зайти на сайт

https://developer.android.com

в поиске ввести название нужного элемента (к примеру `TextView`) и там будет полное описание, а также в информации о XML тегах есть ссылки на эквивалентные программные методы.

Comment: То есть я привильно понял, что каждый виджет нужно во что-то оборачивать?

Comment: @GurebuBokofu, Если хотите настроить его положение в слое, то да

Answer (score 1):

Каждое свойство любого виджета можно настроить программно. Для это используются или методы соответствующего класса (setTextSize, setTextColor, setHintColor etc) или LayoutParams, который должен быть типа контейнера. Т.е. если вьюха лежит в LinearLayout, то и параметры должны быть LinearLayout.LayoutParams